# How to get class instance variables, python

Tags: python, init

I would like to get the names of `__init__` parameters and modify them when the code runs. My class looks like this:

```
class Sample:
    def __init__ (self,indicators:dict):
        self.names = []
        self.returns = 0.0
        for k,v in indicators.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
            self.names.append(k)
```

The input of this class is a random choice of items from a lis; then I assign those random items to a dictionary with integer values.

```
indicatorsList =["SMA", "WMA", "EMA", "STOCHASTIC", "MACD", "HIGHEST_HIGH",
                 "HIGHEST_LOW", "HIGHEST_CLOSE", "LOWEST_HIGH", "LOWEST_LOW",
                 "LOWEST_CLOSE", "ATR", "LINGRES", "RSI", "WRSI", "ROC",
                 "DAY", "MONTH"]

# initializing the value of n
n = random.randint(2,int(math.ceil(len(indicatorsList)/2)))
randomIndList = n * [None]
for i in range(n):
    choice = random.choice(indicatorsList)
    randomIndList[i] = choice

...
...

sample = Sample(randDict)
```

Problem is, I don't know the names of these parameters in `__init__`, and I need to modify them later, for example like this:

```
sample.sma = random.randint(0, maxVal)
```

But I don't know if the object will have `sma`, or `ema`, or any other attribute, because of the way they're assigned randomly.

Comment: `sample.sma = something` will work just fine, even if `sample` doesn't already have an `sma` attribute. Or do you only want to modify attributes that are already set?

Comment: i think i will get AttributeError if i try to call `sample.sma` when `sma` won't be in input dictionary. And yes i need to modify only attributes which are already set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this code:

```py
sample.sma = random.randint(0, maxVal)
```

*will* work, even if `sample` doesn't have an `sma` attribute. It will create one. Try it yourself and see.

But as you specified in your comment that you only want to modify attributes that already exist, that won't help in this case.

What you *could* do, with your existing class definition, is to loop over the `names` attribute you've already defined.

```py
for name in sample.names:
    setattr(sample, name, random.randint(0, maxVal))
```

However, you've basically reinvented a dictionary here, so why not redefine your class to directly use a dictionary?

```py
class Sample:
    def __init__(self, indicators:dict):
        self.indicators = indicators
```

Now you no longer need dynamic `setattr` or `getattr` lookups. They're simply keys and values:

```py
for key in sample.indicators:
    sample.indicators[key] = random.randint(0, maxVal)
```

(This also means you don't need the separate `names` attribute.)